# Keras int_shape returns None in custom loss function

Tags: keras, loss-function

My try to obtain the batch size within a custom loss function using K.int_shape() demonstrated by the code below.

```python
from keras import layers, Input, Model
import keras.backend as K
import numpy as np

train_X=np.random.random([100, 5])
train_Y=train_X.sum(axis=1)

inputs=Input(shape=(5,), dtype='float32', name='posts')
outputs=layers.Dense(1, activation='relu')(inputs)
model = Model(inputs, outputs)#, net_qc])
model.summary()

def myloss(y_true, y_pred):
    n=K.int_shape(y_pred)[0]
    return K.sum(y_pred)/n

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=myloss)
model.fit(train_X, train_Y, epochs=10, batch_size=10)
```

The error message below suggest K.int_shape returns None.  I have tried several things without success, would really appreciate some helps.

```python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test_intshape.py", line 21, in <module>
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=myloss)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 830, in compile
    sample_weight, mask)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 429, in weighted
    score_array = fn(y_true, y_pred)
  File "./test_intshape.py", line 19, in myloss
    return K.sum(y_pred)/n
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 820, in binary_op_wrapper
    y = ops.convert_to_tensor(y, dtype=x.dtype.base_dtype, name="y")
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 639, in convert_to_tensor
    as_ref=False)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 704, in internal_convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 113, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
    return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 102, in constant
    tensor_util.make_tensor_proto(value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape))
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 360, in make_tensor_proto
    raise ValueError("None values not supported.")
ValueError: None values not supported.
```

Answer (score 1):

That is the expected behaviour because `K.int_shape()` doesn't return a symbolic tensor but the current known shape. Well you would only know the batch size at runtime and when constructing the graph it will be `None`. What you are looking for is `K.shape()` instead which will return the symbolic tensor that will have the batch size set at runtime, ie:

```
n = K.shape(y_pred)[0]
```